# Vitis IDE invalid arguments

Tags: sdk, tcl, xilinx, vivado

I'm trying to create a boot image with TCL script on xsct console. But getting error. I couldn't find where I made a mistake. I couldn't find any results in Xilinx's documents and other forums.

> ERROR: source /home/nmi/Desktop/load.tcl

Invalid arguments, name or processor not specified

```tcl
setws /home/nmi/workspace
platform active zc702
app create -name fsbl -hw /home/nmi/Desktop/projeHDF/base_zynq_wrapper.xsa proc ps7_cortexa9_0 -os standalone -template {Zynq FSBL}
app build -name fsbl
exec bootgen -arch zynq -image /home/nmi/workspace/FSBL_system/_ide/bootimage/FSBL_system.bif -w -o BOOT.bin
```

Comment: Is that the content of `load.tcl`?

Comment: Yes, Donal. I'm using text editor for command writing. And load.tcl my script source.

Comment: I've written up how to find the fault, which I think is a generally useful thing. You'll have to do a little more detective work once you've found what the real problem is… but since the system will be telling you “the problem is in _this_ command” that shouldn't be too hard. I hope!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've given us the content of the file in question, the initial issue is that we don't know which command is throwing the error. Tcl *does* know that information and reports it in the error-info stack trace, but the code that runs the `source` is ignoring that stuff and only saying the immediate error message.

We can fix that.

What we want to do is to wrap some extra code around the outside. If you're using Tcl 8.6 inside there, you can do this easily:

```
try {
    # The original code in the file goes in here
} on error {msg opts} {
    puts stderr "ERROR: $msg"

    # Let's put a nice double underline next
    puts stderr [string repeat "=" [string length "ERROR: $msg"]]

    # And now, we print out the error info stack trace
    puts stderr [dict get $opts -errorinfo]

    # Raise the error again; this isn't the properly right way to do it, but it works
    # and the stuff that gets lost is about to be thrown away by the caller
    error $msg
}
```

With 8.5, you'd instead do:

```
if {[catch {
    # The original code in the file goes in here
} msg]} then {
    puts stderr "ERROR: $msg"

    # Let's put a nice double underline next
    puts stderr [string repeat "=" [string length "ERROR: $msg"]]

    # And now, we print out the error info stack trace
    puts stderr $::errorInfo

    # Raise the error again
    error $msg
}
```

Once you know which command is failing, you can look up what the command requires and figure out how things are going wrong.

---

Here's the full example of what I mean.

```
try {
    setws /home/nmi/workspace
    platform active zc702
    app create -name fsbl -hw /home/nmi/Desktop/projeHDF/base_zynq_wrapper.xsa proc ps7_cortexa9_0 -os standalone -template {Zynq FSBL}
    app build -name fsbl
    exec bootgen -arch zynq -image /home/nmi/workspace/FSBL_system/_ide/bootimage/FSBL_system.bif -w -o BOOT.bin
} on error {msg opts} {
    puts stderr "ERROR: $msg"
    puts stderr [string repeat "=" [string length "ERROR: $msg"]]
    puts stderr [dict get $opts -errorinfo]
    error $msg
}
```

Comment: Thanks Donal. I need change 'app create' part guess.

 

Invalid arguments, name or processor not specified
    while executing
"error "Invalid arguments, name or processor not specified""
    (procedure "app" line 180)
    invoked from within
"app create -name fsbl -hw /home/nmi/Desktop/projeHDF/base_zynq_wrapper.xsa proc ps7_cortexa9_0 -os standalone -template {Zynq FSBL}"
Invalid arguments, name or processor not specified

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a command that's been added by the tool system you're working with, and isn't part of the standard Tcl core command set. As such, “consult the documentation” is about all the help I can offer. You may well have better access to the docs for it than I do; I'm really just guessing… (The hardware I work with has an utterly different toolchain, with lots of it developed in-house.)