# Create a .bif file with TCL script

Tags: sdk, tcl, xilinx, vivado

I'm trying create a boot image with TCL script. And i can create if I create fsblTest.bif file via SDK manually. I want to create auto with TCL. How can i create .bif file using TCL ?
My code;

```
 setws /home/nmi/workspace
    app create -name fsblTest -template {Zynq FSBL} -hw zc702 -proc ps7_cortexa9_0 -os standalone
    app build -name fsblTest
    exec bootgen -arch zynq -image /home/nmi/workspace/fsblTest_system/_ide/bootimage/fsblTest_system.bif -w -o /home/nmi/Desktop/bootD/BOOT.bin
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vitis IDE invalid arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258258/vitis-ide-invalid-arguments)

Comment: No, Shawn. My code is working now. But i asking how can i create .bif file with script automaticlly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved. 
Last version of my code :

```
setws /home/nmi/workspace
#app create with hardware,processor..
app create -name fsblTest1 -template {Zynq FSBL} -hw zc702 -proc ps7_cortexa9_0 -os standalone
app build -name fsblTest1

set outputFile [open /home/nmi/workspace/fsblTest1_system/fsblTest1.bif w+]

# .bif file content
puts $outputFile "/* /tmp/bootgen_zynq_fsbl_system16600834677826087177/sd_card_temp/boot.bif */ "
puts $outputFile "/* Command to create bitstream .bin file:       */"
puts $outputFile "/*   bootgen -image <bif_file> -split bin -w    */"
puts $outputFile "/* Command to create BOOT.BIN file:             */"
puts $outputFile "/*   bootgen  -image <bif_file> -w -o i BOOT.BIN */"
puts $outputFile "/*zc702*/"
puts $outputFile "the_ROM_image:"
puts $outputFile "{"
puts $outputFile "\[bootloader] /home/nmi/workspace/zc702/export/zc702/sw/zc702/boot/fsbl.elf"
puts $outputFile "/home/nmi/workspace/fsblTest1/Debug/fsblTest1.elf"
puts $outputFile "}"
close $outputFile
#boot.bin file create
exec bootgen -arch zynq -image /home/nmi/workspace/fsblTest1_system/fsblTest1.bif -w -o /home/nmi/Desktop/bootD/BOOT.bin
```